# Maximum row size exceeds the allowed maximum of 8060 bytes and I can't convert the columns from char to nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, nvarchar

I executed this command in SQL:

```
alter table [Category - Instructions (20927)]
    alter column [NEED Review Order (20977)] nvarchar(100)
```

I'm get this warning:

> Warning: The table "Category - Instructions (20927)" has been created, but its maximum row size exceeds the allowed maximum of 8060 bytes.
> INSERT or UPDATE to this table will fail if the resulting row exceeds the size limit.
>
> Msg 511, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Cannot create a row of size 8074 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060. The statement has been terminated.

How can I solve that?

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL 2019

Comment: you must have different columns in place that when add up you exceed the limitation of 8060 bytes. If you changed the value to nvarchar(max) it will allow you to skip this limitation as it will not stored in row

Comment: What is the actual table definition now? You should review it and try and get the row width down. Maybe you have wide fixed width columns that should be variable length? Maybe you have space taken up by deleted columns that can be reclaimed with a rebuild